# Whirilpool type tub pump isn't working

Tags: plumbing

Pump stopped working, can I still use this as a regular tub without having dirty water getting back into the bath tub??? this is a water type jets not air

Comment: Once you start washing dirt off your body, how does dirty water _not_ get into the tub?

Answer (score 1):

If the jet pipes drain when you drain the tub (which I'd expect to be the case, since otherwise they'd get disgusting even if the pump was working) there shouldn't be any additional issue from them. If you are not planning to repair the pump, you could plug the pipes where they enter the tub to seal them off.